# Storing output results of a command into a an array

Tags: bash

I have a problem  with bash command output. 
I want to save result of command to array and cut first part into [0] and seccond into [1]

```
result=$(findId PATTERN | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 1)
```

Output of findID is:

```
id errorcode nameOfProgramRunned
```

example:

```
12345 "compilation problem" fullScan.java
12346 "other problem" basicTest.java
```

I want to save `id` to `array[0]` and `nameofProgramRunned` to `array[1]`

Main problem is that I want to avoid executing command twice beacause result may be different.

Current code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Enter error code:'
read errorLine

result=$(findID PATTERN | awk '{print $1}')

while read -r line
do

    dir="/proj/jobs/"$line"/screenlog.*"

    if [ -e $dir ]
    then
        if grep -qi "$errorLine" $dir  
        then    
            echo -e "\e[101m$line:\e[49m"       
            grep $dir -i -e "$errorLine"

        fi  
    fi
done <<<"$result"
```

I want to add nameOfProgramRunned to final grep

And I'm using bash

Comment: Both to `array[0]`? You probably meant to use `array[1]`

Comment: Yes it was a mistake. I wan't to save to array[1]

Comment: It would be far better if `findID` could return something more parseable, like tab-delimited records or JSON.

Comment: Changed `findID` its now tab-delimited

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to happen with multiple lines of output? You want to save `id` to `array[0]` but in your example there are two ids, 12345 and 12346. Do you want to overwrite `array` for each line you process, or append, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Edited for open length arrays.

```
echo -e '12345\t"compilation problem"\tfullScan.java' | {
  IFS=$'\t' read -r -a FOO
  echo number: ${FOO[0]}
  echo string: ${FOO[1]}
  echo file: ${FOO[2]}
}
```

Note the IFS being set to tab delimiter

Also take a look at

```
help read # bash built in help
```

Comment: Good idea but what if I add more columns this function will be huge and problematic. Goal is to have 10+ columns

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is safe enough and you can trust your input, then you can also delegate line parsing to shell itself. Something like this:

```
main () {
  findID \
  | while read line ; do
    eval "process_element $line"
    done
}

process_element () {
  local id problem program
  id="$1" ; problem="$2" ; program="$3"

  printf \
    "id: %s, problem: %s, program: %s\n" \
    "$id" \
    "$problem" \
    "$program"
  #do_your_things "$id" "$program"
}

findID () {
  echo '12345 "compilation problem" fullScan.java'
  echo '12346 "other problem" basicTest.java'
}

main
```

[snippet on repl.it](https://repl.it/@meatlink/WastefulLeftPup)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the pipeline to handle all columns at the same time.

Assuming that

- `findID` output is tokenized by TAB and not " ", so that there are no problems with `cut`
- you can save your output arrays into files `file1`, `file2`, ... so that you can retrieve them later

then you can separate columns in the following way:

```
findId PATTERN   | tee >(cut -d$'\t' -f1 > file1) >(cut -d$'\t' -f2 > file2) >(cut -d$'\t' -f3 > file3)
```

I have tested the code with the following minimal example:

```
echo -e '12345\t"compilation problem"\tfullScan.java
12346\t"other problem"\tbasicTest.java'  | tee >(cut -d$'\t' -f1 > file1) >(cut -d$'\t' -f2 > file2) >(cut -d$'\t' -f3 > file3)
```

That is, the pipeline is splitted into different pipelines, one per column

Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503

Answer (score 0):

You should do the splitting of the line within the big loop, that iterates over all findID results:

```
while read -r resultLine
do
    elements=($resultLine)
    line=$(echo "$resultLine" | cut -f1)  # using tab as default delimiter
    issue=$(echo "$resultLine" | cut -f2)
    file=$(echo "$resultLine" | cut -f3)
    ...
done < <(findID PATTERN)
```

Please note some items:

- findID output can be streamed and doesn't need to be cached in a variable
- if you have control over `findID`, ensure that its output delimiter is not contained in the values (space is not a good idea). That saves you headaches when splitting the string.
- If `findID` outputs also a free text, ensure, that this is always the last argument. This way you can use `cut -f3-` to get the rest of the line.

Your double `grep` in the inner loop is inefficient. You probably want to cache the result. This ensures also, that both greps are executed with similar arguments.